# Unfortunately, (my app name) has stopped

Tags: android, xml, eclipse

I am new to android app development and i am using eclipse. i just created 2 activities and added a button to the main activity which is suppose to just open the blank second activity. the app just keeps stopping when i try to to run it on my phone.

this is the logcat in eclipse:

```
04-14 21:16:07.373: E/Trace(27640): error opening trace file: No such file 

or directory (2)

04-14 21:16:07.603: E/AndroidRuntime(27640): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-14 21:16:07.603: E/AndroidRuntime(27640): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.inveslator/com.example.inveslator.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-14 21:16:07.603: E/AndroidRuntime(27640):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2071)
04-14 21:16:07.603: E/AndroidRuntime(27640):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2096)
04-14 21:16:07.603: E/AndroidRuntime(27640):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:138)
04-14 21:16:07.603: E/AndroidRuntime(27640):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1207)
04-14 21:16:07.603: E/AndroidRuntime(27640):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-14 21:16:07.603: E/AndroidRuntime(27640):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
04-14 21:16:07.603: E/AndroidRuntime(27640):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4787)
04-14 21:16:07.603: E/AndroidRuntime(27640):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-14 21:16:07.603: E/AndroidRuntime(27640):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-14 21:16:07.603: E/AndroidRuntime(27640):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
04-14 21:16:07.603: E/AndroidRuntime(27640):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
04-14 21:16:07.603: E/AndroidRuntime(27640):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-14 21:16:07.603: E/AndroidRuntime(27640): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-14 21:16:07.603: E/AndroidRuntime(27640):    at com.example.inveslator.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:21)
04-14 21:16:07.603: E/AndroidRuntime(27640):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
04-14 21:16:07.603: E/AndroidRuntime(27640):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
04-14 21:16:07.603: E/AndroidRuntime(27640):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2035)
04-14 21:16:07.603: E/AndroidRuntime(27640):    ... 11 more
```

Below is the androidmanifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.inveslator"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity 
            android:name=".Second">
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

And this is the Mainactivity.java:

```
package com.example.inveslator;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button b = (Button) findViewById(android.R.id.button1);
        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Second.class));

            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

I would be glad to know whats wrong. thanks in advance
```

Comment: Have you tried running the debugger to see what's null and why?

Comment: no but i just changed android.R.id.button1  to R.id.button1 as answered and it worked for me

Comment: Using the debugger should probably be your first step in any problem you had. If you had used it here  you would have been able to narrow your question considerably.

Comment: sure. i will use the debugger next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume it's about this line

```
Button b = (Button) findViewById(android.R.id.button1);
```

I guess you have a `Button` with `id = button1` in your xml layout. In this case use:

```
Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

`android.R` is for sdk resources and `R.id.some_id` is for `id`s you create